# Rewrite URLS using global.asax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make some friendlyurls in my vb.net (.net 4) project and I'm trying to do it using something I read about global.asax and Application_Beginrequest but I can't get it to compile.

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim httpContext As System.Web.HttpContext = httpContext.Current
    Dim currentURL As String = currentURL.Request.Path.ToLower()
    If currentURL.IndexOf("widgets") > 0 Then
        objHttpContext.RewritePath("products.aspx?ID=123")
    Else
        objHttpContext.RewritePath(httpContext)
    End If
End Sub
```

Above is what i'm trying but it's erroring on the objHttpContext. is there another method? Ideally once I get the above method working I'm going to be attempting to use a database call to work out the URLs. So any suggestions in that direction will also be very welcome. I'm trying to get away from having to install anything on IIS as it's a load balenced enviroment that I'd rather not install something on every server.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want use rewriting, when you can do it really easy using asp.net routing?

Please, look at the following link for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: ... "routing to provide features that are used only in MVC applications and in Dynamic Data applications"

Comment: @mustafaöztürk, refresh your knowledge, routing is applicable to webforms as well.

Answer (score 7):

You should access HttpApplication.Context. Here is how I do it (C#):

```
string reqPath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
if(reqPath=="/")
    newPath="/Pages/PL/Main.aspx";
if (newPath != "")
    HttpApplication.Context.RewritePath(newPath);
```

As I can see in documentation you should be able to use exactly the same syntax to access the context in VB.NET.

You could also use II7 url rewrite module if you really wanted.

Comment: What is the advantage over asp.net routing if I may ask?

Comment: @walther: Routing is an MVC feature not standard ASP.NET. Question did not mention MVC.

Comment: See, this is why you're wrong. Routing is part of webforms as well since .NET 4, which OP stated he's using as well. Don't be stuck in the past, .NET constantly evolves and we need to keep up with it :)

Comment: A little harsh comment but taken. Learned something important. ASP.NET is not my main speciality.

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounded harsh. I'll definitely try to be more polite next time. Thank you for letting me know. Maybe I learned something important too :)